# Weird behaviour in EF (possible bug)

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I think I might have found a bug in Entity Framework.

I'm using Database First with MVC3.

I have the following table in my database:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[InstructionStep](
    [instructionID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [step] [numeric](18, 0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [description] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [recurrence] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [parameters] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [secuence] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [time] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_InstructionStep] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [instructionID] ASC,
    [step] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY
```

I'm using linq to EF to save/edit information into this table. The thing is... the "time" column, NEVER gets a value. I triple checked and the model DOES have a value for the time property of the object, but when I pass it to EF, it never makes it to the database. This is the code I use to create a new record:

```
            using (Models.SAIMBehrEntities db = new Models.SAIMBehrEntities())
            {
                if (step.description != null)
                    step.description = step.description.ToUpper();
                if (step.parameters != null)
                    step.parameters = step.parameters.ToLower();

                db.InstructionSteps.AddObject(step);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
```

this is the code I use to edit a record:

```
            Models.InstructionStep s = db.InstructionSteps.Where(x => x.instructionID == stepM.instructionID && x.step == stepM.step).FirstOrDefault();
            if (s != null)
            {
                s.parameters = stepM.parameters;
                s.description = stepM.description;
                s.recurrence = stepM.recurrence;
                s.secuence = stepM.secuence;
                s.time = stepM.time;                    
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
```

Everything else gets saved, except the "time" column. Now, I fired up sql profiler. This is the query generated by the create method:

```
exec sp_executesql N'insert [dbo].[InstructionStep]([instructionID], [description], [recurrence], [parameters], [secuence])
values (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4)
select [step], [time]
from [dbo].[InstructionStep]
where @@ROWCOUNT > 0 and [instructionID] = @0 and [step] = scope_identity()',N'@0 uniqueidentifier,@1 nvarchar(max) ,@2 decimal(18,0),@3 nvarchar(50),@4 decimal(18,0)',@0='9013B4B0-28FB-4C52-912D-3598A8E13880',@1=N'DEMO DESCRIPTION',@2=1,@3=N'none',@4=1
```

And this is the query generated by the update method:

```
exec sp_executesql N'update [dbo].[InstructionStep]
set [description] = @0, [recurrence] = @1, [parameters] = @2, [secuence] = @3
where (([instructionID] = @4) and ([step] = @5))
select [time]
from [dbo].[InstructionStep]
where @@ROWCOUNT > 0 and [instructionID] = @4 and [step] = @5',N'@0 nvarchar(max) ,@1 decimal(18,0),@2 nvarchar(50),@3 decimal(18,2),@4 uniqueidentifier,@5 decimal(18,0)',@0=N'DEMO DESCRIPTION',@1=1,@2=N'none',@3=1.00,@4='9013B4B0-28FB-4C52-912D-3598A8E13880',@5=1386
```

So... yeah. The "time" column gets selected after an update/insert. Why? beats me...

I tried changing the column name to "timestep" and worked correctly.

Is this a normal behaviour? am I just being plain stupid or is this a bug?

Thanks!

Comment: This is expected behaviour *if* your column is marked as `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed`. If you've set that, you've told Entity Framework that `time` is a field that's server-calculated, and that's retrieved from the database after an update. Could you show your model and mapping?

Comment: Ok. Somehow the StoreGeneratedPattern for the time column was being Computed. But I swear I did not do it! Thanks @hvd

Comment: @hvd place it as answer please.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka Given that this was apparently not a manual modification, I don't consider it an answer yet: an answer would explain how, when, and preferably even why the `Computed` option got set.

Comment: @hvd I used your SQL to create a table in a new database, then used Generate from Database in the EDM wizard to create a model and checked the resulting mapping. The time column was mapped correctly and did not have Computed set. Often Computed is used with timestamp (or rowversion) columns for concurrency. Is it possible that at some point the column was a timestamp?